# RestKit Object Mapping Crashes on null JSON value for BOOL

Tags: ios, restkit

I've got some JSON coming back from a service which at some times will have null instead of true/false for an attribute which is a boolean; Like this:

```
"hide_locations" : null,
```

My object to receive this value has a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL hideLocations;
```

My mapping is configured like this:

```
RKObjectMapping *retVal = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[self class]];
[retVal mapKeyPath:@"hide_locations" toAttribute:@"hideLocations"];
```

But when I perform the mapping, RestKit 0.10.3 is crashing on this line:

```
[self.destinationObject setValue:value forKeyPath:attributeMapping.destinationKeyPath];
```

in
    - (void)applyAttributeMapping:(RKObjectAttributeMapping *)attributeMapping withValue:(id)value

in RKObjectMappingOperation.m with the following error:

2012-11-13 09:33:04.352 Tests[73816:5f03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '[ setNilValueForKey]: could not set nil as the value for the key hideLocations.'

It seems quite odd to me that a mature framework like this doesn't handle this situation more gracefully, so I can't help but think I've configured something incorrectly. I would appreciate any insights you might have.

Answer (score 1):

null is not a valid boolean in JSON, only true and false, so I think your object mapping in objective-c is wrong to make it a BOOL. You should probably fix the json to represent a boolean value properly (then you won't have any nulls to crash on) or treat hide_locations/hideLocations as an NSString and use `[hideLocations boolValue]` in your code if you need to.

Comment: Oh, I realize that null is not a valid BOOL. That's not my question at all. My question is that it seems surprising that RestKit is not fault tolerant for this kind of invalid input and I'm asking if there's a way to configure it to gracefully handle this situation.

Comment: the answer is no, it assumes you have not tried to map null to a bool. looking at the restkit source there is no check or config that would avoid this.

Comment: JSON isn't fault tolerant. One character wrong, and your whole input won't get parsed. If you get a null value when you expect a bool then the server probably intends you to treat these differently.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that this kind of input is just not well tolerated by RestKit, unfortunately.

The best usable advice I have received so far to protect against this problem is from Blake Watters of RestKit, who says:

> You should probably just implement `setNilValueForKey:` on your target
>   object and handle it appropriately.

So, there you have it, either pre-sanitize your JSON, or arm against calls to `setNilValueForKey:`

Ref: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/restkit/dlYVd0zCr3c